# How to set/pass in a custom class object to a custom view in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, mpandroidchart

I have a custom view which is a wrapper over the Mp Android Chart library. It takes an implementation class that actually calls the methods of the MP Android Chart library. I want this implementation to be provided by which ever fragment is using this view. In this regards, how can I pass / set a custom implementation object in the view?

One idea I am currently having is to set it through attributes but can't find any proper format for the attribute.
Another idea would be to simply write a public method to the sets the implementation class and does the initialization of the view once again

```
class CustomLineChart(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0):
FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    val lineChartImpl = DefaultChartImpl() // providing default implementation of line chart
    init {
        initLineChart()
    }

    fun initLineChart() {
        // initialize line chart view
        lineChartImpl.init()
    }

    fun setImplementation(customImpl: LineChartImpl) {
        lineChartImpl = customImpl
        initLineChart()
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with just getting the custom chart view (e.g. with `findViewById` or from a binding) and calling `chart.setImplementation(...)` on it in the Fragment?